# Internet Connection Sharing bypassing MAC Filter

Tags: connection, bypass, internet-filter

My university gives me an internet connection by Ethernet, DHCP but they have installed MAC Filtering to allow only using my PC.

I have a separate Network Interface Card (NIC) at my PC, that I have connected to a WLAN Router. I use freeproxy to set up a proxy server at my PC to connect my laptop and ipod simultaneously to internet.

Problem is that all apps do not support proxy (especially skype in ipod/ipad), particularly those requiring special ports. Is there any other way to share internet?

My router (TL-WR340GD) has a MAC address cloning option, which I tried, but even if I clone to my PC's MAC Address it does not share internet and only my PC can access internet via it (that has same MAC).

Basically the config is:

```
Ipod ===> WLAN Router ====> PC NIC-2 ===> PC ====> PC NIC-1 ====> University Internet
```

Answer (score 6):

Plug everthing into your router, and give the router a clone'd MAC address:

```
iPod══╗   ┌────────────┐
      ╚═══╡            │
iPad══════╡ TL-WR340GD ╞═══University Internet
      ╔═══╡            │
 PC═══╝   └────────────┘
```